# cakephp sort problem using join

Tags: cakephp

why no work sort by "author"? Not throw any errors, just unsorted

```
   function index()
        {
            $this->paginate = array(
                    'limit' => 5,
                    'order' => array(
                        'Post.id' => 'asc',
                    ),
                    'fields' => array('Post.id', 'Post.title', 'User.name AS aut_name'),
                    'joins' => array(
                        array(
                            'table' =>'users',
                            'alias' =>'User',
                            'type' =>'LEFT',
                            'conditions' => array(
                                'Post.author = User.id'
                            )
                        )
                    )
            );  
            $posts = $this->paginate();
            $this->set('posts', $posts);
        }

<tr>
        <th><?php echo $paginator->sort('ID', 'id'); ?></th>
        <th><?php echo $paginator->sort('Author', 'User.name'); ?></th>
        <th><?php echo $paginator->sort('Tilte', 'title'); ?></th>
        <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Your code says its sorting by the Post.id, not by the author

Comment: But when i click on "<th><?php echo $paginator->sort('Tilte', 'title'); ?></th>
" sort by title, then why no sort by Author when i click on <th><?php echo $paginator->sort('Author', 'User.name'); ?></th>?

Answer (score 1):

The code suggests that the User.name field is being returned as "aut_name", maybe set the sort argument to use that field name instead?

```
<th><?php echo $paginator->sort('Author', 'aut_name'); ?></th>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should do this way
in controller:

```
'fields' => array('Post.id', 'Post.title', 'User.name')
```

in view:

```
 <th><?php echo $paginator->sort('Author', 'User.name'); ?></th>
```